# Choosing an MVVM Framework for Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have used MVVMLight before in a few projects.  Has anyone who has used Prism before know of any significant benefits over MVVMLight.  Or do they pretty much have the same features?

Comment: I use MVVMLight.  Works pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism is made primarily for extensibility with some components that can be used to implement MVVM designs.  Personally I think that Prism is too heavy for simple SL applications.

Check out this earlier post on the subject: [MVVM Light + Unity or Prism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750255/mvvm-light-unity-or-prism)